# Python/Pandas: How to select a cell value, given 2 values in the same row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 3 columns:

```
ID     datetime     X
10     01/01/2018   3
10     02/01/2018   4
12     02/01/2018   8
12     07/01/2018   12
```

Now my question is, what is the best way to get X given an ID and date?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Do you think [pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe) ?

Comment: Is `ID` the index?

Comment: No, ID is not the index

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html):

> .loc is primarily label based, but may also be used with a boolean array.

So you can use it for boolean indexing and combine both conditions with a  bitwise AND operator, `&`. Note that the conditions must be separated by parenthesis.

Example `ID` and `date`:

```
ID = 10
date = '02/01/2018'
```

Indexing of the dataframe:

```
df.loc[(df.ID == ID) & (df.date == date), 'X']
1    4
```